# Camel @Produces unit test

Tags: junit, apache-camel

Can someone point me to some examples of Junit or Arquillain tests to test a class that defines a @Produces for a datasource: example of class in Camel project to be tested

```
/*
 * Inject the datasource defined in Fuse's standalone-*.xml file.
 */
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/datasources/fang")
private DataSource fangDataSource;

@Produces
@Named("fangDataSource")
public DataSource getDataSourceFang() {
    return fangDataSource;
}
```

Comment: Are you using EAP / JEE applications? If so then try to look for general JEE unit testing with CDI. You can also look at the wildfly-camel project at https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel

Comment: Yes ...using EAP ...checked out the CDI and that was good solution ...Thanks